# I need this calculator to redirect the user for input incase he enters the wrong one

Tags: java, switch-statement

In the third input, it asks for a number to be entered to do the specific operation. 
But when for example "5" is entered, it doesn't automatically send it to default section to display the message "the value doesn't exist.".
In addition to that, I need it to display the input prompt again and ask for a number from 1 through 4 to be entered. thx

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Specialized {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = getInput("Enter a number: ");
        String s2 = getInput("Enter a number: ");
        String op = getInput("Enter: 1 = Add, 2 = Subtract, 3 = Multiply, 4    = Divide ");

         int opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);
         double result= 0;

        switch (opInt) {
        case 1:
            result = addValues(s1,s2);
            break;
        case 2:
            result = subtractValues(s1,s2);
            break;
        case 3:
            result = multiplyValues(s1,s2);
            break;
        case 4:
            result = divideValue(s1,s2);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("the value doesn't exist.");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static String getInput(String prompt) {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print(prompt);
        System.out.flush();

        try {
            return stdin.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private static double addValues(String s1, String s2) 
         throws NumberFormatException {
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        double result = d1 + d2;
        return result;
    }

    private static double subtractValues(String s1, String s2) {
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        double result = d1 - d2;
        return result;
    }

    private static double multiplyValues(String s1, String s2) {
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        double result = d1 * d2;
        return result;
    }

    private static double divideValue(String s1, String s2) {
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        double result = d1 / d2;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  SO is not a code-writing service, so a simple statement that you need work done is generally not well received here.  If you are having problems, you need to include your *specific* issue, along with any input you give, and output/errors you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you surround the "getting of input from user" with a `while` loop until you get your desired input. Like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = getInput("Enter a number: ");
        String s2 = getInput("Enter a number: ");

        //notice I declare this outside now so I can compute for new value inside loop
        int opInt = 0;
        double result = 0;

        //you can change the condition later if you add more options
        while(opInt < 1 || opInt > 4) {
            String op = getInput("Enter: 1 = Add, 2 = Subtract, 3 = Multiply, 4    = Divide ");
            //recalculate the choice
            opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);

            switch (opInt) {
                case 1:
                    result = addValues(s1, s2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = subtractValues(s1, s2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = multiplyValues(s1, s2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = divideValue(s1, s2);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("the value doesn't exist.");
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: I like this alot ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To have the the input repeat, you can do something like this:

```
double result= 0;
do {
     String op = getInput("Enter: 1 = Add, 2 = Subtract, 3 = Multiply, 4    = Divide ");

     int opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);

     boolean repeat = false;         

    switch (opInt) {
    case 1:
        result = addValues(s1,s2);
        break;
    case 2:
        result = subtractValues(s1,s2);
        break;
    case 3:
        result = multiplyValues(s1,s2);
        break;
    case 4:
        result = divideValue(s1,s2);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("the value doesn't exist.");
        repeat = true;
        break;
} while (repeat);
```

The do while loop runs through once no matter what, then checks a condition at the end to see if it should repeat.

Comment: Declare `result` outside, asker needs to print `result` outside the loop.

Comment: @Incognito is right, make sure to declare any reused variables outside the loop

Comment: got it ! Thank you:) So "boolean repeat =false"  is to prevent infinite loop, right?

Comment: @MarieMirbekian yes, we reset the flag to false so that it will only repeat again if the user continues to fail to provide valid input

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code, and it *does* print "the value doesn't exist" when 5 is entered. However, you are correct in that it doesn't ask it again(because you haven't used a loop);

To continuously ask the user to enter a number as long as their number isn't between 1 and 4 inclusively, you need to use a [while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop.

Something like

```
while(opInt > 4 || opInt < 1){ //keep asking}
```

Comment: Thank you ! How do I ask it to repeat? Do I just copy & paste the prompt into the while loop so I have a duplicate prompt elsewhere?

Comment: just add `while(opInt > 4 || opInt < 1){
         op = getInput("Enter: 1 = Add, 2 = Subtract, 3 = Multiply, 4    = Divide ");
         opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);
        }` under `int opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);`

Answer (score 1):

Use do-while loop. This will prompt user again and ask for a number from 1 through 4 to be entered :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = getInput("Enter a number: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter a number: ");
    double result = 0;
    boolean repeat;

    do {
        String op = getInput("Enter > 1 = Add, 2 = Subtract, 3 = Multiply, 4 = Divide :");

        repeat = false;

        switch (Integer.parseInt(op)) {
        case 1:
            result = addValues(s1, s2);
            break;
        case 2:
            result = subtractValues(s1, s2);
            break;
        case 3:
            result = multiplyValues(s1, s2);
            break;
        case 4:
            result = divideValue(s1, s2);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("the value doesn't exist.");
            repeat = true;
            break;
        }

    } while (repeat);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: awesome ! so what is "flag" exactly? flag = repeat?

Comment: aaaa! very interesting